# Unix Shell Scripting using Date Command

Tags: shell, date, unix, format, sh

Ok, so i'm trying to write a scrpit to wc files using the date command. The format of the files, for example, goes like this: **testfile20170104.gz**.

Now the files are set up to have yesterday's date with the format **yyyymmdd**. So if today is 1/5/2017 the file will have the previous day of 1/4/2017 in the yyyymmdd format, as you see in the example above.

Normally to count the file all one needs to do is simply input: **gzcat testfile20170104.gz|wc -l** to get the word count.

However, what I want to do is run a script or even a for loop that gzcat the file but instead of having to copy and paste the filename in the command line, I want to use the date command to input put yesterday's date in the filename with the format of yyyymmdd.

So as a template something like this:

**gzcat testfile*.gz|wc -l | date="-1 days"+%Y%m%d**

Now I know what I have above is COMPLETELY wrong but you get the picture. I want to replace the '*' with the output from the date command, if that makes sense...

Any help will be much much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
filename="testfile$( date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d ).gz"
zcat "$filename"
```

Comment: Sorry, what? A non-sh for-loop?

Comment: for example will i still be able to use the same code by doing:

for file in /data/dir
>do
>filename="testfile$( date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d ).gz"
>zcat "$filename"
>done

will that still work?